# React Jest TypeError: Cannot read property 'baseUrl' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, axios, jest-mock-axios

I have a simple login api call where the base url is in config file, code below

**api.js**

```
export const login = (username, password) => {
    Axios.post(`${config.loginApi.baseUrl}/login`, {
        username,
        password
    })
    .then(res => res)
    .catch(e => e);
};
```

I wrote the test case(s) below,

**api.test.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { login } from './api';
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';
import config from 'config';


describe('signin signup Api', () => {
    
afterEach(() => {
        jest.restoreAllMocks();
    });

    it('logs in successfully', (done) => {
        const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
        mock.onGet(`${config.loginApi.baseUrl}/login`).reply(200, { data: '1234abcd' });
        login('dee@gmail.com', 'test').then((res)=>{
            expect(res).toEqual('1234abcd');
            done();
        });
});
```

or the other test case I wrote earlier

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { login } from './api';
import config from 'config';

jest.mock('axios');

it('logs in successfully', async () => {
      axios.post.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve({ data: '1234abcd' }));
      await expect(login('dee@gmail.com', 'test')).resolves.toEqual('1234abcd');
});
```

I researched and found **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60992357/how-to-test-axios-with-config-option)** close to my issue. But in all the cases I'm getting
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'baseUrl' of undefined**

Why is this not able to know the baseUrl?

I tried mocking the config,

```
jest.mock(config);
```

got TypeError: moduleName.split is not a function.

Please suggest a fix/workaround.

Adding more info on the config

in config folder, I have

```
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = config;
```

in development environment, it will pick this config from dev.js, in prod - prod.js and so on

in public folder, dev.js file I have

```
loginApi: {
        baseUrl: 'https://abcd.com',
        mocks: true,
        mockDelay: 2000
    }
```

Comment: Are you aliasing the `config` module? If not, you should change your import with a relative path.

Comment: @Christiaan its the global config. I added more details on this config above and the solution that worked for me below.

Comment: Although your answer will work, I still suggest importing the config file using a relative import `./config` or creating an [alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias). Now you are destroying the purpose of the `dotenv` package.

Comment: @Christiaan Ok i'll add a relative import but I'm not sure how you feel this is destroying the purpose of dotenv.

Comment: Because you will now have a configuration on two separate locations. One in your `.env` file and one your `setupTests.js`. The first works with environment variables, while your `setupTest.js` implementation will not. This can lead to unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @Christiaan I didn't have baseUrl, other test details in config/env.

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix for this issue,

in the setupTests.js, I added

```
global.config ={
   loginApi: {
        baseUrl: 'https://abcd.com',
        mocks: true,
        mockDelay: 2000
    } 
}
```

This fixed that TypeError: Cannot read property 'baseUrl' of undefined issue.